# Different Django CMS menus for different django apps

Tags: django, django-cms

Maybe I'm just blind, but I couldn't really find anything that would help me solve this problem. I've got a Django project where I'm using Django CMS, for example to display a menu on all sites. Now I want to add an additional Django sub-app, which should display a completely different menu. Is there any preferred way to do this?

For now I arrived at following solution. I'm using two `cms_menus.py` files, one that defines the `NavigationNodes` used for all hitherto sites and one that defines the `NavigationNodes` for the new sub-app. So each `NavigationNode` has a namespace (out of the box), that basically indicates where it should be displayed. And I got a `Modifier` that removes all `NavigationNodes` that have a differing namespace if it is set:

```
class NamespaceModifier(Modifier):

    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        if post_cut:
            return nodes

        if namespace is not None:
            # only return nodes from given namespace
            return [node for node in nodes if node.namespace == namespace]

        return nodes

menu_pool.register_modifier(NamespaceModifier)
```

The motivation for this is, that the `show_menu` template tag accepts the `namespace` paramter, as specified in the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/stable/reference/navigation.html#show-menu): "The fifth parameter, `namespace` specifies the namespace of the menu. if [sic] empty will use all namespaces." (Although it should be noted that it needs to be added after the template name, e.g. `{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 "website/nav.html" "TestMenu" %}`, where `TestMenu` is the namespace.)
The custom `Modifier` is necessary, as `show_menu` doesn't seem to do anything with the `namespace` except setting it. I kind of expected that out of the box only the `NavigationNodes` from the given `namespace` would be displayed, but obviously I'm wrong there...

Is there a better solution for the (I would think quite common ) requirement to use different menus? Obviously, in my solution above, I could also use the `attr` of the `NavigationNodes` if they cannot be mapped to a Node-namespace.